# How to re-compress the .cmp file, created by stsadm export command, after editing

Tags: sharepoint, compression, moss, sharepoint-designer, stsadm

I need to manually edit some of the files inside of the .cmp file created by stsadm export command (or SharePoint Designer backup).  I can extract the files and make the edits, but don't know how to properly re-compress the files so that the resulting .cmp file is valid for use with stsadm import.

Comment: I do think this question fits StackOVerflow better than ServerFault because it goes beyond what an admin would normally do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format for CMP files is Microsoft CAB. So if you can find an archiving utility that will recompress to that format it may work.

Be careful as what you're doing probably isn't supported. Make sure it's thoroughly tested!

Answer (score 2):

[Makecab.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/198038) will do the trick.

http://anuraj.wordpress.com/2008/05/02/creating-cab-files-using-makecabexe/

http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/articles/UsingVisualStudioAndMsBuildToCreateWssSolutions.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue recently, and used Cab File Maker 2.0 to rebuild the .cmp file. A write-up of the process I used can be found here - http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/01/editing-cmp-files-to-fix-lookup-field.html

Comment: I tried Cab File Maker but it wanted me to add files one at a time. I gave up and went with @Ryan's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found that the [-nofilecompression flag](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261866.aspx) can be used to import uncompressed files, but still looking for the ability to re-compress the Content Migration Package (cmp).